# Add Different numbers for Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I want to get information for about 6,000 profiles and they each have links to theirs with a specific number in order from 1-6000. I want to get a specific image from each of their profiles all in one page.  Here is the code to get it for user 1's profile... Where it says u1 it needs to replace the 1 with each of the different numbers.

```
<span id="boutiqueimage"></span>
<script>$('#boutiqueimage').load('/u1 #field_id14 dd')
                                      </script>
```

Comment: Well, you can *get* the images by calling `.load()` in a loop.  But with the current setup that would result in each response overwriting the previous one in the target element.  What do you want to do with all 6000 images?  Add them all to that element?  Does their order matter?

Comment: @David Some may not even have the images and others will, I basically want to get them so that I can display them all and look through the different users images and let others see it as well. Could you possibly show me a better way to get them all in a loop like you said?

Comment: @mplungjan The some profile id isn't very descriptive for help?

Comment: With the lack of information in the question that is what I posted until more info is given. Do you want to append the 6000 images to the boutiqueimage? and what is /u1 returning exactly?

Comment: @mplungjan I posted a similar comment below to another member with the details and a link. Basically the u1 is the first user aka myself and each member has a different number which goes in order from which they joined. I want to get the main image from each of their profiles. Here's mine to reference the actual page and coding. http://www.designerssociety.net/u1

Comment: I see. So for example "Your friends" does something like that. The code in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26190385/295783) should do it. It is hard to test since I do not have access to the site to add the code. Perhaps you can set up a test version with less data on it? The pages are VERY heavy to run 6000 times, since the ajax will download the complete page. A better solution would be to create a small server process that would return just the necessary string. For example the content of the table with your image, which now has class forumline

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it seems like a simple loop would do the trick, but the problem isn't necessarily *fetching* the images but what to do with them when you *get* them.  For that, you don't want to use `.load()` because it's just outside of your use case.  (It assumes you want to set the fetched content to an element, but you want to *append* the fetched content to an element.)

To do that, we need to perform almost the same functionality as `.load()`, so let's see [how it does its thing](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/load.js).  Looks like it's just a standard call to `.ajax()` with this as its success handler:

```
self.html( selector ?
           jQuery("<div>").append( jQuery.parseHTML( responseText ) ).find( selector ) :
           responseText );
```

Seems simple enough.  And we can simplify it a little more, since we know we have a `selector` value:

```
self.html(jQuery('<div>').append(jQuery.parseHTML(responseText)).find(selector));
```

Now instead of calling `.html()` on `self`, we call `append()` on our target element:

```
$('#boutiqueimage').append(jQuery('<div>').append(jQuery.parseHTML(responseText)).find(selector));
```

We also need to explicitly define `selector`:

```
$('#boutiqueimage').append(jQuery('<div>').append(jQuery.parseHTML(responseText)).find('#field_id14 dd'));
```

Now we can wrap that in the AJAX call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/u1',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function(responseText) {
    $('#boutiqueimage').append(jQuery('<div>').append(jQuery.parseHTML(responseText)).find('#field_id14 dd'));
});
```

This should replicate the functionality of `.load()` for our needs.  *Now* we can put it in a loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 6000; i++) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/u' + i,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function(responseText) {
        $('#boutiqueimage').append(jQuery('<div>').append(jQuery.parseHTML(responseText)).find('#field_id14 dd'));
    });
}
```

This *should* make 6000 AJAX requests where the `url` of each is a different value of `i` from the loop.  Keep in mind that there's *no* guarantee that responses are going to come in the same order they were requested.  So it's *very* unlikely that the resulting images are going to be sorted from 1-6000.

**Edit:** In response to comments, perhaps running the requests in serial instead of parallel would help.  Let's encapsulate the operation into a function and call it from its own success handler.  Maybe something like this:

```
function fetchImage(id) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/u' + id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function(responseText) {
        $('#boutiqueimage').append(jQuery('<div>').append(jQuery.parseHTML(responseText)).find('#field_id14 dd'));
        if (id < 6000) {
            fetchImage(id + 1);
        }
    });
}
fetchImage(1);
```

This will load them a lot slower, since it's only one at a time.  But I guess 6000 simultaneous requests wasn't a good idea in the first place :)  This will also load them sequentially, which is a bonus.

Comment: Well it appears to be doing something when I open the console I'm getting this error message a lot Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable) and some of this Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  I know that some may not have an image up for it but wanted to show both codes for help?

Comment: It is very poor advice fetch 6000 images in a loop. Instead execute the next fetch on successful receipt of each image.

Comment: @LeandraKatelyn: I've updated the answer with a modified approach, might be worth a try.

Comment: @mplungjan: Good point.  I guess I was caught up in the implementation that I didn't even notice the scale.  6000 simultaneous requests is probably... not ideal.  I've updated the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @David hmm it didn't work maybe there's a better way to go about this.. Here's one of the actual pages for example to look at and I'd want to get the main image on the page, which is the field14... maybe there's another suggestion you have like having them upload from here to php storage or something? I'm not super sure on how that all works but if you have any ideas I'd appreciate the help otherwise thank you for trying. http://www.designerssociety.net/u1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you posted code works for profile 1 and the profiles are numbered from 1 to 6000 and you do not want paging, then try this. NOTE: Accessing fragment does result in download of the entire page!
A better solution is to set up a server process that returns only the necessary html.

```
var max = 6000,cnt=1;
function loadNext() {
  $("#container").append('<span id="boutiqueimage'+cnt+'"></span>'); // add a span
  $('#boutiqueimage'+cnt).load('/u'+cnt+' #field_id14 dd', 
    function (responseText, textStatus, req) { // if error
      if (textStatus == "error") {
        $('#boutiqueimage'+cnt).html("image "+cnt+" not found");
      }
      else {
        if (cnt<max) {
          cnt++;
          loadNext(); 
        }
      }
  });
}

$(function() {
  loadNext(); //start
});
```

using

```
<div id="container"></div>
```